# Want to stop the Foreground service on clicking the notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, media-player, foreground-service

Am trying have notification using foreground Services, and I had given media player below and it is in a loop.

now I want to stop that repeated player/Serving on clicking the notification
My Service Class be Like

I had given getExtra and PutExtra in the notification Intent and the main Activity, Is that Way Works?

```
`var player: MediaPlayer?=null
val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val input = intent!!.getStringExtra("inputExtra")
    createNotificationChannel()
    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    notificationIntent.putExtra("cancel",true)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0, notificationIntent, 0
    )
    player= MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI)
    player?.isLooping=true
    player?.start()
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
        .setContentText(input)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_alarm_24)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()
    startForeground(1, notification)


    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
   player?.stop()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "Foreground Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
    }

}


override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}
```

}
`

My Main Activity Class be like

```
` val playBtn by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.playBtn) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    playBtn.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            //val serviceIntent =  Intent(this@MainActivity, androidServ::class.java);
           // serviceIntent.putExtra("cancel", "Foreground Service Example in Android")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForegroundService(Intent(this@MainActivity, androidServ::class.java))
            }
        }

    })



    stopService(this)


}

private fun stopService(context: MainActivity) {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(context, androidServ::class.java)
    serviceIntent.getStringExtra("cancel")
    val an =androidServ()
    an.player?.stop()
}`
```

Comment: You can make your service [bound](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services), then you can control it from UI.

Comment: yeah thank you so much.. i had solved this using BroadcastReceiver